# Gritty sugar cookie dough. Raw. And cooked

Tags: sugar

I have made peanut butter cookie dough 2x   both times the cookie dough came out gritty  Baked and unbake I put the dough in frig for 3 hrs  1st batch  the 2nd batch in the frig for 3 days. still is grainy. (You can see the sugar crystals on the side of the bowl) I have made same cookie dough for year. This is the first time this has ever happened.